# How to make a UIBarButtonItem like this

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uibarbuttonitem

How can I make a UIBarButtonItem like this:
[image]

I can't find it in the SystemItem values.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's probably using something like:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:@"info.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil]
```

I tried with:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]];
item.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
```

but it seems like with a custom view the bordered style doesn't get applied.

Answer (score 18):

The Image button which you have called info button.It's an system button,

Use below to get it as your **rightBarButtonItem**

```
UIButton* myInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]; 
[myInfoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(InfoButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myInfoButton];
```

Here is the documentation link to [UIButtonType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIButtonType)

Comment: Right, but if you try that, you'll see you get the plain style, and not the bordered style shown in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Swift's version of @Jhaliya's answer for quick copy-paste:

```
let infoButton = UIButton(type: .InfoLight)

infoButton.addTarget(self, action: "InfoButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

let infoBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton)

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoBarButtonItem
```