# how do I set a UIBarButton to have the info symbol

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Hopefully an easy one this but I'm a little stumped

I have a bar button that i want to set to an info symbol

the symbol is in the [iOS human interface guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1) but not in the drop down in interface builder's attributes inspector.

How do i get this image ?

cheers

Comment: That list in the docs is examples, not the set that are (publicly) available via the API. Use a custom image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a custom type button.

```
UIButton* myInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]; 
[myInfoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(InfoButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myInfoButton];
```

or

you can try [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290322/1307844)

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the Button object in Xcode's object library.  (The Button object, not the Bar Button Item object.)
2. Drag the Button object to your toolbar.
3. Hold Control and Shift while clicking on your new button.
4. Select the Button from the pop-up menu.  It will be the bottom item in the menu.
5. In the Attributes Inspector, set the button type to “Info Light”.

Demo:

[image: adding info button to toolbar in storyboard]

Comment: cheers rob - nice graphic , Ive gone with the other answer as I had a bar button i wanted to display the info symbol. Looks like it doesn't prove the info symbol for a bar button item so you have to create a regular button and assign that to the bar button item