# How to use info button on a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

How can I use the info light on a `UIBarButtonItem`?

I don't want to use a custom image because the result is not very nice.

I would like to use the Apple "info" button on a UIBarButtonItem using Swift.

Comment: In code or via Interface Builder?

Comment: Code, I don't think it is possible by Interface Builder! Thank You

Comment: @Danny182 There is a way by Interface Builder.  See my answer to the similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955353/how-to-add-a-standard-info-button-to-a-navigation-bar-in-ios

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no direct way to create such a bar button using the [`UIBarButtonItem` APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/).

You can although use a custom view configured with a `.InfoLight` `UIButton`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290230/how-to-make-a-uibarbuttonitem-like-this):

```
// Create the info button
let infoButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)

// You will need to configure the target action for the button itself, not the bar button itemr
infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getInfoAction), for: .touchUpInside)

// Create a bar button item using the info button as its custom view
let infoBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton)

// Use it as required
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoBarButtonItem
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need any more help.

Answer (score 5):

Adapting mokagio's excellent answer to Obj-C:

```
UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getInfoAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem* infoBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoBarButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it easily reusable like this:

```
class InfoBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {

    init(_ type: UIButtonType = .infoLight, target: Any, action: Selector) {
        super.init()
        let button = UIButton(type: type)
        button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.customView = button
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }    
}
```

then you can use like this:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
            InfoBarButtonItem(.infoLight, target: self, action: #selector(anAction(_:)))
```

Comment: @KevinStewart that would be a matter of taste though.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4, iOS 12, Xcode 10**

Another way to do this:

1. Drag a Bar Button Item from the objects menu to your navigation bar.
2. Control drag from the barButtonItem to your view controller to create an outlet.
3. In viewDidLoad you can specify the UIButton.customView as follows.

   ```
   let infoButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)

   infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoAction), for: .touchUpInside)

   infoBarButtonOutlet.customView = infoButton 

   //where infoBarButtonOutlet is the outlet you created in step 2.

   // Be sure to add @objc before func when you create your function.
   // for example: 
   @objc func infoAction () {

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Interface Builder as follows:

1. Drag a UIButton object onto the toolbar
2. Set the button type as "Info Light"