# How to add a standard info button to a navigation bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'd like to add a right bar button with the system's info icon to a navigation bar. But I see that `UIBarButtonSystemItem` does not provide such type of button. On the other hand, so I tried with a `UIButton` of type `UIButtonType.infoLight`, but I am not allowed to assign it to `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this can be achieved using `UIButton` object of type `.infoLight`

```
let infoButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoButtonTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

alternatively:

by adding `infoImage` to your `Asset catalog` and create `barButtonItem` using below code

```
let infoButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "infoImage"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.infoButtonTapped))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoButton
```

Comment: This is rather inconvenient.

Comment: That's even more inconvenient. There already is an info button pre-made. Since OP is asking for the default one, why make it complicated with loading pics and such?

Comment: @LinusG. You can't use UIBarButton with type . InfoLight as its not provided in UIBarButtonTypes but can be used with UIButton types. Please provide the solution if you have rather than commenting on the approcaches.

Answer (score 5):

I have found an easier way to add info icon to a navigation bar using Interface Builder.

1. Don't add Bar Button Item to the navigation bar
2. Add a Button to the UIView
3. Change a button type to Info Light
4. Drag and drop the button to the right corner of the navigation bar. It is all. Bar Button Item will appear automatically and the added info Button will be under the Bar Button Item 
   (Then, make an action as usual for the Button)

Comment: Drag the UIButton right onto the navigation bar! (or Toolbar, in my case).  You don't have to drop it on the view first.  It works great.

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Comment: One more step, set the initial frame for the button.
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 30)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.0**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let infoButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
    infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: infoButton)
}

@objc func infoButtonTapped() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the infoButton image into your assets and set as barButton by providing the name .

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"infoImage.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(barButtonAction)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

In Swift

```
  let item = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "infoImage.png"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(barButtonAction))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I didn't want to provide an image but use the standard icon

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *doneBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame...];
[doneBtn setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
doneBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0];
[doneBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doSubmit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:doneBtn];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```